# ViewData Int32 must be of type IEnumerable in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am getting an error that I cant seem to fix:

> "The ViewData item that has the key 'posts.Id' is of type
>   'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'."

**ViewModel/PostViewModel**

```
namespace MyBlogger.ViewModel
{
    public class PostsViewModel
    {
        public Post posts { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Tags { get; set; }

        private List<int> _selectedPostTags;
        public List<int> SelectedPostTags
        {
            get
            {
                if (_selectedPostTags == null)
                {
                    _selectedPostTags = posts.Tags.Select(m => m.Id).ToList();
                }
                return _selectedPostTags;
            }
            set { _selectedPostTags = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

**PostController: (Manually Setting the Id for now)**

```
public ActionResult EditPostTag(int id = 12)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    var postsViewModel = new PostsViewModel
    {
        posts = db.Posts.Include(i => i.Tags).First(i => i.Id == id),
    };

    if (postsViewModel.posts == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    var tagsList = db.Tags.ToList();
    postsViewModel.Tags = tagsList.Select(o => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = o.Name,
        Value = o.Id.ToString()
    });

    ViewBag.UserID =
            new SelectList(db.BlogUsers, "Id", "Email", postsViewModel.posts.Id);

    return View(postsViewModel);
}
```

Comment: In your dropdownlist for--> you need <SelectListItem> not <SelectList>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.posts.Id, (SelectList)ViewBag.Id, Model.posts.Id);
```

but your controller method does not assign a `SelectList` to a `ViewBag` property named `Id`, hence it it null in the view, which results in that exception.

You need to assign the value of `ViewBag.Id` to a `SelectList` before you return the view, although since you are using a view model, I recommend you include a property `public SelectList PostsList { get; set;}` in your view model and assign it to that instead and use it as

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.posts.Id, Model.PostsList);
```

Side note: Its not clear what you think the 3rd parameter (`Model.posts.Id`) of your current usage is doing (its for generating a `null` value label option)